# Proper module packaging for CloudML

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I have a Python project structured as follows:

- project/ Contains:
- setup.py ; project/
  The inner project/ folder contains a **init**.py empty file, folders with submodules, a conf/ folder containing only .yaml files (e.g. foo.yaml) and a s_main.py script (my main entry point)

This is my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

NAME = 'project'

package_data = {'':['conf/*.yaml','*.yaml'],'project':['conf/*.yaml']}

if __name__ == '__main__':

setup(
  name=NAME,
  version=1.0,
  description='Foo',
  author='someone',
  author_email='a@b.com',
  packages=find_packages(),
  include_package_data=True,
  package_data=package_data,
  zip_safe=False)
```

When I try 'pip install project/' it works fine on my PC and I see the conf/ folder with all my *.yaml files in [...]/python2.7/site-packages/project/conf/
When I run cloudML locally, it also works. I use the following command:

```
gcloud ml-engine local train \
  --package-path=path_to_project_module \
  --module-name=project.s_main \
  --distributed \
  -- \
  conf/myConf.yaml \
  conf/myParams.yaml
```

But when I run it on cloudML, it doesn't work. I run the following command :

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training JOB_100 \
  --package-path=path_to_project_module \
  --module-name=project.s_main \
  --staging-bucket=myBucket \
  --region=europe-west1 \
  --config=mlConfig_file \
  -- \
  conf/myConf.yaml \
  conf/myParams.yaml
```

The log clearly shows that the conf/ folder was never included in the built package and my run fails because the expected *.yaml files were not found. 
Any idea?

Comment: For some odd reason, it works fine when I set 'include_package_data' to False !!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try manually packaging using:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

And then staging the resulting .tar.gz in a Cloud Storage bucket.

Once you do that, you should be able to refer to your pre-staged package using --package-uris flag on the gcloud command (when submitting a job to the service).

See if that helps unblock you.

Comment: I think it should work. I have used `python setup.py sdist` and it generated what I needed (the *.yaml files were included in the package). But for it to work, I had to set `include_package_data` to False. It doesn't seem right but it solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to try is not using `package_data` and `include_package_data`, but rather using `data_files` ... at least that is what I have used in my own scenarios where I needed to have additional data files in a source distribution.

Something like:

```
data_files=[('.', 'conf/*.yaml','*.yaml']),
            ('project':['conf/*.yaml'])
           ]
```

Maybe that will work?